# How does terminal palette work

Tags: command-line, colors

So my question is basically simple. What is this color palette in color preferences of the terminal? Where can i see which color does what. What every color from this palette is responsible for? You can see that there is a color for text, for bold text and for background. But what's with the palette?
Thank you.

Comment: For `gnome-terminal` (the default on most Ubuntu installations), the color palette can be found by opening the Terminal and going to `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Default` > `Edit` > `Colors`. Does that help?

Comment: i know where this color palette is. I want to know what each color in that palette is responsible for.

Comment: It really depends on the application

Comment: on what application? on a terminal emulator or on a program that i'm running in the terminal? And how it depends? how programs use this palette?